# How to calculate the time difference between each timestep in Python

Tags: python, pandas, timedelta

I have a dataframe index by seconds. I want to create a new column `dTime` that shows the change in time from Time T and T-1 in seconds. I tried `df["dTime"].total_seconds()`, however, I get an attribute error *"'Series' object has no attribute 'total_seconds'"*.

```
data = ["prod.dat")]
df = pd.DataFrame(index=read_dat(data[0], header_lines=3).index.values)
df["dTime"] = pd.to_timedelta(df.index, unit='s')
df
Time        Prod        dTime
662558400   1.975595    7668 days 12:00:10
662558400   1.975916    7668 days 12:00:25
662558400   1.976396    7668 days 12:00:47.500000
662558500   1.977118    7668 days 12:01:21.250000
66258500    1.9782  7668 days 12:02:11.879999995
```

In this example above I would want the change in time seconds

```
Time        Prod        dTime
662558400   1.975595    0
662558400   1.975916    0
662558400   1.976396    0
662558500   1.977118    100
66258500    1.9782  0
```

Comment: You can use `pd.Series.diff` to calculate the difference between consecutive rows. You can use `pd.Series.dt.total_seconds()` on a series with timedeltas to get the total seconds. Your example data is very unclear to me though

Comment: @Chrysophylaxs the dataset is just an example. More important on calculating the change in time for each timestep in a timeseries. How would I get the total seconds from here?
`df1= pd.Series.diff(df)`
`df1=pd.Series.dt.total_seconds(df1)`
With this I get the same attribute error but this time **delegate_method**

Comment: Call `diff` on the column you're looking to compute the difference between each row for: i.e. `df["Time"].diff()`

Comment: I was able to compute the difference from this command `df1= pd.Series.diff(df)`. The issue that I am stuck at is that I cannot get total seconds from `df["dTime"]`. This is the command I tried `df2=pd.Series.dt.total_seconds(df1)`.It says AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'total_seconds'

Comment: `df["dTime"].dt.total_seconds()`

Comment: Since `df["dTime"]` is a new variable which is not associated with datetimelike values, `.dt` accessor does not work. Is there a way to make a column datetime?

Comment: Use `pd.to_datetime`